# Discord.py AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'guild'

Tags: discord.py

I recently got helped for doing a voice time tracking in python for my Discord bot and everything works fine except 1 thing.

Here's my code:

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_voice_state_update(self, member, before, after):
        if member.bot: #checking this before anything else will reduce unneeded file operations etc
            return
        with open('data/voice_leaderboard.json', 'r') as file: 
            voice_data = json.load(file)
        new_user = str(member.id)
        guild_id = str(member.guild.id)
        if new_user not in voice_data[guild_id]: #this adds a new user to the guild dict if they're not in it yet
            voice_data[guild_id][new_user] = {
                "total_time" : 0,
                "join_time" : None} 
        userdata = voice_data[guild_id][new_user] #this is to make the next code clearer, adding things to this dict also adds them to the voice_data dict, it just make the code "cleaner"

        #after making sure the user exists you gotta check if they're joining or leaving a vc(and reject all the other options), plus if they change vc within the same guild it should keep counting. There's multiple ways to do this
        if(before.channel == None): #this is when they join a vc (they werent in one before so they gotta have just joined one)
            join_time = round(time.time())
            userdata["join_time"] = join_time
        elif(before.channel.guild == after.channel.guild): #wrote this to only check if they changed vc within the same guild, but then I realised it can also catch all the mute/deafen events yay.
            return
        elif(str(after.channel.guild.id) != guild_id): #this will check if the channel they're in after the event (we wanna record the time passed if its None or a different guild, both of which will get triggered by this)
            if(userdata["join_time"] == None): return #this will catch errors, if they were to happen
            userdata = voice_data[guild_id][new_user]
            leave_time = time.time()
            passed_time = leave_time - userdata["join_time"]
            userdata[total_time] += passed_time
            userdata["join_time"] = None #preventive measure against errors
        with open('data/voice_leaderboard.json', 'w') as update_user_data:
            json.dump(voice_data, update_user_data, indent=4)
```

I get this error when I disconnect:

```
    elif(before.channel.guild == after.channel.guild):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`after.channel` is `None` because the user is not connected to a `channel` after disconnecting.

You will have to cater for cases like this.

```py
...
elif after.channel is None:
    return
elif(before.channel.guild == after.channel.guild):
    return
...
```

Comment: Sorry, it should just be `after.channel is None`. Fixed

Comment: No because if I do that, if I disconnect the bot will just continue tracking my voice time while I'm not in a vocal anymore

Comment: Then add your code to the new `elif` statement to stop tracking your voice time.